# Erro com a função random

Tags: python-3.x, random

Este é o código que escrevi em Python:

```
from random import randint

a = randint

print(a)
```

Ao utilizar a função `randint` neste simples código, o console dá me o seguinte erro:

```
<bound method Random.randint of <random.Random object at 0x0000015E1A1D4FD0>>
```

Answer (score 2):

Isso que você recebe **não é um erro**! Isto é o valor literal de sua função que você obter através do código abaixo:

```
>>> v = randint.__str__() # Devolve uma string
>>> print("\n" + v)

<bound method Random.randint of <random.Random object at 0x0000015E1A1D4FD0>>
```

Há dois problemas no seu código. O primeiro problema é que você não chamou a função. Para chamar uma função, utilize os parênteses (abrir e fechar parênteses) como no exemplo abaixo:

```
var = func()
```

O segundo problema do seu código, é que você não passou os argumentos necessários para chamar a função `randint()`.

Para executar essa função, você deve passar um valor inicial e um valor final. Dessa forma, o `randint` irá retornar um valor aleatório entre `a` e `b`, exemplo:

```
x = randint(0, 3) # Retorna um valor entre 0 e 3
```

---

O que você estava fazendo no seu código, era atribuir a função `randint` à variável `a`, tornando ambas as mesmas funções. Exemplo:

```
a = randint
a is randint # True

randint(0, 3)
a(0, 3) # Posso executá-la assim como no randint já que ambos são idênticos.
```

Answer (score 1):

Esse valor:

```
<bound method Random.randint of <random.Random object at 0x0000015E1A1D4FD0>>
```

Não trata-se de um erro, é o valor literal da função `randint`.

---

Perceba que você importou a função `randint` do `random` mas não invocou a mesma, apenas exibiu ela no console.

Veja, eu posso fazer isso com outras funções, imprimindo seu valor literal:

```
print(print)
```

Inclusive, eu poderia utilizar o valor presente na variável `a` para invocar a função, veja esse exemplo:

```
from random import randint

#A variável a agora contém a função randint
a = randint

#A variável b agora contém a função print
b = print

#Logo eu posso chamar a randint pela variável a
c = a(1,3)

#E exibir no console(print) com a variável b
b(c)
```

> Exemplo online: https://repl.it/repls/PeacefulFriendlyMeasurements

---

Se você deseja fazer uso da função randint, precisa abrir os parenteses e informar os parâmetros necessários:

```
from random import randint

a = randint(1,2)

print(a)
```

> Veja esses exemplos online: https://repl.it/repls/MediumRealisticDisc
>
> Documentação do random: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html

Answer (score -2):

Esta a utilizar mal a função.
exemplo:

```
from random import randint
a = randint(1, 10)
print(a)
```

Falta o range.